# API development alongside Azure cloud

Tags: javascript, rest, api

Im newbie in development APIS with coulds (but had good experience in DEVELOPMENT in java and python , javascript)
I want to do a REST API that:
Allow users to query an API for a certain phrase, and get the sentiment of the comments users had to stories with that phrase in the title, on HackerNews's "top stories".
HackerNews exposes a public API - https://github.com/HackerNews/API

this REST API accepts a GET request with a phrase, and returns aggregated statistics of the sentiment of the comments that had that phrase in its headline.

e.g.

GET awslambda.com/sentiment?pharse=RYANC

response:

{

```
"comments" 100,

"positive": {

    "avg": 0.52,

    "median": 0.58

}
```

}

I can use any cloud like AWS, GCP, Azure .. how can I do that API? I don't have any clue, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways of approaching developing a REST API.

At minimum, you should consider the following:

1. Which Cloud provider? (e.g. [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/))
2. What platform will the API run on? (e.g. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), [PHP](https://www.php.net/))
3. Will there be any underlying architectural patterns? (e.g. [Serverless](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-serverless-architecture), [Micro Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices))
4. Are there any existing frameworks that will support your development? (e.g. [Serverless](https://serverless.com/))

There are numerous factors that may contribute to each of these decision. Ultimately you need to look at what you're trying to achieve and what best fits your requirements. Factors such as cost, and prior experience may restrict which options are relevant to you.

Comment: Any help please?!

Comment: @Ryan based on the information you've provided I'd suggest looking at the [serverless npm package documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/).

Comment: what factors should I take in order to choose cloud? I mean lets assume myplatform is node.js as what should I choose?